# Why can't humans throw objects at bullet speed when the force involved seems so small?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, projectile, biology

The force that propels a bullet should at least be similar in intensity to the force experienced as recoil and the force exerted on the target. But these forces seem really low (the equivalent of a shove).

If all it takes to make a small object achieve bullet speed is the equivalent of a shove, why can't humans throw objects at these speeds?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you worked out how much net force you'd have to apply to a three-to-five gram bullet in order to accelerate it to some hundreds of meters per second within a space of less than one meter?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I looked it up online, a 4.4g bullet achieving 322m/s through a 0.75m barrel receives an average force of 304N. For comparison humans can push with 1000N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As The Photon wrote in a comment, the issue is that you have to accelerate your hand as well.  So while the 4.4g bullet only needs 304N to accelerate (by your numbers in the comments), your 400g hand has to reach the same speeds on roughly the same distances, requiring on the order of 30000N, well outside the range of the human body.

You may, however, be interested in some tools we've developed to improve our mechanical advantage, letting us accelerate things without accelerating our hands at the same time.  The sport of [Jai Alai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jai_alai), for instance, has a hand held device called a cesta which lets us more efficiently transfer energy into a ball.  The record for the 125-140g ball was 302km/h (188mph).  This was the fastest human-driven ball until Jason Zuback drove a ball at 328km/h -- a golfball hit by a golf club.

Comment: Cort Ammon, just for curiosity's sake, who's Monica?

Comment: @DavidWhite Monica Cellio was a moderator on Stack Exchange until recently, whom many believe was unjustly dismissed.  You can find out more from many meta posts, such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334399/summing-up-the-main-issues-the-story-so-far/334417#334417)

Comment: @David it's a lot of drama scattered on lots of posts.

Comment: This is just the start, as you then have to worry about the structural integrity of the arm. Sports physiologists reckon that world-class pitcher (both baseball and fast-pitch softball) run their arms near the failure of their elbow tendons, and stopping an arm from hundreds of meters per second would rather exceed those stresses.

Comment: Cort and Kyle, the road to hell is paved with good intentions.  I looked at the link that Cort posted, and I agree with Kyle ... the drama got extreme.  Trying to force people to violate their core beliefs in the name of inclusion will lead to this kind of drama every time.  Moderators, good luck ... you've opened Pandora's box, and the path forward is totally unpredictable.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is simply that we can't move our arms quickly enough. We have the strength- a lever-action airgun shows that the equivalent of a good shove is enough to fire a pellet- but we don't have the speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you could accelerate the gun to the same speed it has right after the shot, you could use it to hit the bullet and make it fly at the right speed. However, this speed is still very large and you cannot use your shoulder hand system to do it. Our body can stop a gun moving at such speed but cannot bring it back to it.