# Why can't humans throw as fast as bullet and what law is involved?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, biology

If desert eagle 7g bullet can accelerate the velocity to 560m/s (In Average)
And baseball 149g can only be accelerate to the velocity of 45m/s (In History)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't humans throw objects at bullet speed when the force involved seems so small?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/517485/)

Answer (score 4):

In order to accelerate a bullet to 560 m/s a second with your arm, you have to get you finger tips to that speed.

Approximating the throw as a circle, and the radius of the circle being about a meter you can calculate the acceleration required to hold the circle as being:

$a=\dfrac{v^{2}}{r} = \dfrac{560^{2}}{1} = 313,600\; \mathrm{m/s^2}$

As you can see the acceleration is ludicrously high to the point it'd completely detach your arm from it's socket and they'd be a soggy mess where your arm used to be.

Comment: The acceleration value you provided is actually not quite right. That corresponds to the **radial component** of acceleration necessary to keep the bullet in circular motion at the said speed. You'd first need tangential acceleration to get the bullet to travel at that given speed.

Answer (score 1):

We can't provide enough power.

You'd have to accelerate your hand to an extremely high speed. That requires force you just cannot provide.

We can however try to enhance our throwing, through some clever tools. An example would be the baseball that you cited. The reason hitting a baseball with a bat results in greater speed than hitting it with our hand is the following:

If we hit the baseball with our hand, then our hand (and the baseball) will deform. Kinetic energy that could otherwise be transferred to the ball will instead produce deformation.

Due to the deformation, amongst other factors, the collision time will increase, so the average force the ball experiences will decrease. Force is smaller, acceleration is smaller, which means, speed is smaller.

In the case of a baseball bat, more kinetic energy is transferred to the ball because, unlike our skin, the wooden bat will not deform. Also we can accelerate the tip of the bat faster than we could our hand.

This is actually why car bumpers are made of plastic nowadays instead of metal. Plastic deforms, and thus 'absorbs' the shock in the event of a collision. The impact force on the human is therefore decreased, so it's safer.

In air soft guns, the energy is stored by compressing the air. When the pressure is released, the force will accelerate the bullet. In real firearms, the firing is caused by a chemical reaction.

In summary, we *cannot* store the required potential/kinetic energy needed, expect to release that stored energy almost instantly, and then have most of it converted to kinetic energy for the projectile. That's why we invent machines that can store, convert, and quickly release that energy for us. Such machines must be very powerful -- power in the physical sense, as in $P_\mathrm{avg}=\dfrac{\mathrm{\Delta energy}}{\Delta\mathrm{time}}$. The higher the power output, the more energy is transferred per unit time.